# Check a string of random letters for an english word

Tags: javascript

I'm developing a website for fun that adds a random character to a div element on every key press. I have that part working, but what I need is for the program to check if an English word has been created out of the random characters and highlight that word. I've tried many things, and none have worked. Preferably this would highlight it regardless of whether or not there are spaces surrounding the word, but I will be very happy with really any working code.

This is my current JS for random character generation and autoscrolling, also with some code that doesn't work that is meant  to search the code.

```
var letter = 1
var number = 1
const alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '\u0020']
function typingfunction() {
    number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 27)
    letter = alphabet[number]
    document.getElementById("typing").innerHTML = `${document.getElementById("typing").innerHTML}${letter}`
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight * document.body.scrollHeight);
    var input = document.getElementById("typing").innerHTML;
    var fs = require('fs');
    fs.readFile("words_alpha.txt", function(words) {
       var words = words.toString().split('\n').filter(function(word) {
           return word.length >= 4;
    })});
    var output = [];
       words.forEach(word); {
           if (input.match(word)) {
               output.push(word);
           }
    };
    console.log(output);
}

window.addEventListener('keydown', typingfunction)
```

Comment: In order to check for an English word, you need to have a complete English dictionary to search.  Do you have that?  Also, you know that `'\u0020'` is exactly the same as `' '`, right?  That's a space.

Comment: @TimRoberts 1. Yes, I have a 4mb text file of every english word. 2. Yes, I do know that.

Comment: Is your dictionary located on the web server?  You will need to send an AJAX request to some process on the server to look for file names.  Do you have a web server app yet?

Comment: "I've tried many things, and none have worked"--hearing that you tried things doesn't do us much good, unfortunately. The point is seeing the attempts so we can work with them. Would you be able to share your attempts? Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen The most promising thing I tried was a modified answer from another post. This is what I have currently that doesn't work (it's in typingfunction under the last line) 

var input = document.getElementById("typing").innerHTML;
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile("words_alpha.txt", function(words) {
   var words = words.toString().split('\n').filter(function(word) {
       return word.length >= 4;
})});
var output = [];
   words.forEach(word); {
       if (input.match(word)) {
           output.push(word);
       }
};
console.log(output);

It doesn't log anything ever.

Comment: Please [edit] that into the post. I can't read the code like that. It's weird to be seeing fs, require and document/keypresses all in the same code. Are you in the browser or node?

Comment: I am very confused about whether your dictionary is being looked at on the frontend via JS or on a server. The part of the code which checks whether a string of characters matches a word in the dictionary seems like the most important part but is missing from your question.

Comment: @AHaworth I've updated my original post with some search code that I had previously deleted, if you want to look at that.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still confused. Are you using some system that isn't in your tag list (?nodejs?) Have you put your code through a syntax checker? Are you seeing any errors on your console? I can see that the file containing the dictionary is just each word followed by a newline and that you are discarding words less than 4 characters long - but have you logged the result of the read and split etc to make sure you are getting what you want/expect?

Answer (score 0):

The code for testing a word basically is OK but there was a syntax error in your code (incorrect format for an anonymous function) and also the words array was only declared inside a function but you tried to use it outside the function.

This code slightly reorganises things to take account of this.

I have no way of testing the nodejs filereading (assuming it is nodejs) so if that causes a problem add the tag to your question to get more help in that area.

The code listens for a click on the window and sets the input HTML empty so several trials can be run.

```
var letter = 1
var number = 1
const alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '\u0020']
function typingfunction() {
    number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 27)
    letter = alphabet[number]
    document.getElementById("typing").innerHTML = `${document.getElementById("typing").innerHTML}${letter}`
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight * document.body.scrollHeight);
    var input = document.getElementById("typing").innerHTML;   
    var output = [];
       words.forEach(word => {
           if (input.match(word)) {
               output.push(word);
           }
    });
    console.log(output);
}
// first set up the array of words from the file containing them
let words; //declare words here so it can be used later on
let fs = require('fs');
    fs.readFile("words_alpha.txt", function(allWords) {
       words = allWords.toString().split('\n').filter(function(word) {
           return word.length >= 4;
    })});

window.addEventListener('keydown', typingfunction);
window.addEventListener('click', function () {document.getElementById("typing").innerHTML = '';});
```